# GetX Get.ToNamed doesn't work inside child

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

I've wish to create a simple app that keeps the bottomNavigationBar constant, changing it's child.
I suppose that GetX is the best and the simplest way to implement that but,I am facing an unexpected problem.

Here's the code snippet:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final NavController navController = Get.put(NavController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        //child: navController.bodyContent[navController.selectedIndex],
        child: Obx(
          // ignore: missing_return
          () {
            String _test =
                navController.bodyContent[navController.selectedIndex];
            print(_test);

            return Profile(); //well, it's hardcoded but it works. 
            //I can realise my logic to change screens right here...
            //... but I'm not sure it's good enough
            
            //And I can see recived from controller text but cannot use it as desighned.            
            //return Text(_test); 


            //return Get.toNamed(_test); //that's what i supposed to realize but faced an error:
            //The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.
          },
          //() => Text(navController.bodyContent[navController.selectedIndex])),
          //    navController.bodyContent[navController.selectedIndex]),
          //child: Showcase(),)
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(() => BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: [], //here i specify my BottomNavigationBarItems
            currentIndex: navController.selectedIndex,
            onTap: (index) => navController.selectedIndex = index,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

And the controller:

```
class NavController extends GetxController {
  final _selectedIndex = 0.obs;
  final List<String> bodyContent = [
    '/showcase',
    '/liked',
    '/publish',
    '/messages',
    '/profile',
  ].obs;

  get selectedIndex => this._selectedIndex.value;
  set selectedIndex(index) => this._selectedIndex.value = index;
}
```

Well, it partly works.
I can receive bodyContent routes but cannot just use it.
Want to keep logic of show child at controller.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Get.reset();
Get.toNamed('${Routes.ITEMS}', parameters: parameters);
```